# If I used for charging sumsong for blackberry it not charge properly why?

Tags: battery, charging

If I used for charging sumsong for blackberry it not charge properly why?
also is it effecting life of the battery?

Comment: Hey mate, you really need to fix your question, it's hardly understandable...

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but a look into our [charging tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/charging/info) most likely will answer your question.

Answer (score -2):

It's recommended to only use a charger from the same manufacturer to avoid issues.

Comment: Says who? Any references to your claim? I've never adhered to such a rule, and never had any issues. Several devices from different manufacturers, using their chargers cross-wise. Moreover, power specifications are normed with the USB connection.